# moment.js add month but bad format

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

i'm using moment.js to manipulate dates. I have a value stored in a field, i would like to get this value et add 1 month. Here is my code:

```
var myDate = $('#CRUEventModal #rdvStartDate').val();
alert('Date i get:' + myDate); // I get: 25-05-2016
myDate = moment(myDate).format("DD-MM-YYYY");

alert('Date i get transformed:' + myDate); // I get: NaN-NaN-0NaN
var new_date = moment(myDate, "DD-MM-YYYY").add('months', 1);
alert('End date: ' + new_date); // I get: -62164630800000
```

But i would like this result: 25-06-2016

Help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`format` is used to format a momentjs date, not to specify how to parse it.
If you want to parse a string as a date with a specific format, you should use `moment(string, format)`. Have a look [at the documentation here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

```js
var myDate = "25-05-2016";
console.log('Date I get: ' + myDate);
myDate = moment(myDate, "DD-MM-YYYY");

console.log('Date I get transformed: ' + myDate);
var new_date = moment(myDate, "DD-MM-YYYY").add(1, 'months'); // 'months' should come
                                                              // after 1 with the latest
                                                              // versions.
console.log('End date: ' + new_date);
console.log('End date (human readable): ' + new_date.format("DD-MM-YYYY"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, i already tried to put months after the int, i obtained the same result. So i do not though i needed to format the date AGAIN. Thanks again.